# Combining multiple backend services into one cloud endpoint API

Tags: google-cloud-endpoints

Is it possible to combine multiple apps running in GKE into the same Google Cloud Endpoints service? For example, say I have a Flask app and also a Nodejs app serving both serving different api resources, can I combine these two backend services into the same cloud endpoints API. Thanks!

Comment: Were you able to find a solution?

Answer (score 6):

Looks like there is a way!

You can add `x-google-backend:` to any of the end points, as long as you are deploying it as an actual gateway, not a Kubernetes side card.

Example:

```
# Specify a backend to handle all routes, paths will be appended to the base path
x-google-backend:
  address: https://backend-hash-uc.a.run.app
paths:
  /hello:
    get:
      summary: Greet a user
      operationId: hello
  /goodbye:
    get:
      summary: Bid a user goodbye
      operationId: goodbye
      # Per operation overrides
      # Path is overwritten and path parameters are specified as query params
      x-google-backend:
        address: https://backend2-hash-uc.a.run.app/goodbye
```

Source: https://groups.google.com/forum/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!msg/google-cloud-endpoints/DehPzXAOzxI/Q3ABVK6zCQAJ